# solidity converting number strings to numbers

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I'm writing a converter for integer strings to integer values, which seems like it should be pretty easy since the string values are `0x30` ("0") through `0x39` ("9").  So just subtract 0x30 and multiply by 10**exp based  on the position in the string.
I just can't figure out how to get the hex - int conversions to work,
particularly when I need to do the math part.  Would be relatively easy if there were a conversion from bytes1 to int or uint, but I can't seem to find that.

Here's what I've got so far, but compile errors on the indicated line.

```
uint  val=0;
bytes   memory stringBytes = bytes(numberString);
for (uint  i =  0; i<stringBytes.length; i++) {
   uint exp = stringBytes.length - i;
   bytes1 ival = stringBytes[i];
   bytes1 jval = ival - 0x30;
   
   val +=  (jval * (10**exp));  <--doesn't compile.
}
return val;
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case anybody stumbles across this -- this seems to work for strings representing positive integers.  I don't think too hard to extend to string like "-23.1".

```
function st2num(string memory numString) public pure returns(uint) {
        uint  val=0;
        bytes   memory stringBytes = bytes(numString);
        for (uint  i =  0; i<stringBytes.length; i++) {
            uint exp = stringBytes.length - i;
            bytes1 ival = stringBytes[i];
            uint8 uval = uint8(ival);
           uint jval = uval - uint(0x30);
   
           val +=  (uint(jval) * (10**(exp-1))); 
        }
      return val;
    }
```